# Run bash file when SSH login failure

Tags: sshd

I'm trying to execute a bash file whenever there's a failed attempted login via SSH onto my Ubuntu server.

Can anyone suggest how to do this?

---

As an aside, I'm currently running a script on a successful logon using the `/etc/pam.d/sshd` file. I'd like to do the same for unsuccessful logons.

```
session optional pam_exec.so /usr/bin/my-script.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is [fail2ban](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8).  It's designed to run as a daemon and watch the sshd logfile for login failures.  While its normal function is to update an `iptables` config to ban the IP address that failed to log in (multiple times), you can configure it to do something else instead such as invoke your custom script.  (this is found in the manual linked above in the "Actions" section)

Comment: Thanks for this. This seems a sensible route. I've installed fail2ban and have been looking at the `action.d` directory where I believe I need to put a call. Are you able to tell me where I'd put the call to a `.sh` file?

Comment: @StephenEllis I haven't customized fail2ban like this, I've only used it to block connections using its pre-configured settings.  So I don't have a specific suggestion to make.